# How to use await key word on react native?

Tags: react-native

I tried to use await/async on react native,but I got unexpected token error.

I added the code blow in my javascript source file:

```
var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('STORAGE_KEY');
```

My react native version is 0.15.0.

Do I need to add some configuration to use async/await?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a try catch block similar to the documentation?

Comment: @NaderDabit I tried wrapping it in a try catch but result in the same error.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I'm using async/await in my react native app and didn't have to do anything to configure or enable it in my project. My usage takes the form of...

```
async getCache(key){
    try{
        let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
        return value.json();
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log('caught error', e);
        // Handle exceptions
    }

}
```

**Note**: 
*If you use an await inside a function that is not explicitly declared with async, you'll end up with an Unexpected token syntax error.*

Comment: I read the release note and found that the babel support was added on the version 0.16.I think that why I failed.

Comment: Note that if you use an `await` inside a function that is not explicitly declared with `async`, you'll end up with an `Unexpected token` syntax error.

Comment: I'm using 0.28.0 and am not able to use async or await.

Comment: double check your .babelrc file is setup correctly
`{ "presets": ["react-native", "es2015", "babel-preset-stage-3"] }` and you might find some clues here to help you troubleshoot. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6901

Comment: Did you check this on Android as well?
I have some problems with my Android App whereas the iOS counterpart works just fine.

Comment: I haven't, but I'm confident it should work since JavaScriptCore is used

Comment: @ChrisGeirman it looks like it does not work with fat arrow () => {} function declaration

Comment: @SERG can you give an example of what you've tried? I'd think this would work. 
`async getCache = (key) => {...}`

Answer (score 7):

> Do I need to add some configuration to use async/await?

Yes. `async` is still not a finalized part of the specification; they're currently considered "Stage 3" (Candidate).

You can enable all Stage 3 language proposals in your `.babelrc` by using the [`stage-3` preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/). Alternatively, you can add [just the `async` plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/).

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `.babelrc` file in the root of your project, you need to add the `"react-native"` preset:

`npm i babel-preset-react-native --save-dev`

Then in your `.babelrc` file add the following:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

More information [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/babel-preset).

Answer (score 1):

After reading [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4844#issuecomment-204035720) on the react-native GitHub issues, the following worked for me:

Add the following npm module:

`npm install babel-preset-react-native-stage-0 --save`

Add the following configuration to your `.babelrc` file:

`{ presets: ['react-native-stage-0'] }`

Clear your cache:

```
$ watchman watch-del-all
$ ./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh --reset-cache
```