# React Native: return the value fetched by AsyncStorage.getItem() in function

Tags: react-native

I have a working OrderHistory model:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

const tokenKey = "orderHistory";

export default class OrderHistory extends Object {
  static ordersPlaced() {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
  }
}
```

and in my component I have this:

```
  showConfirmOrderModal() {
    alert("booya");
  }

  onBuyButtonPress() {
    OrderHistory.ordersPlaced().then((amount) => {
      switch(amount) {
        case null:
          this.showConfirmOrderModal();
          break;
        default:
          this.addToCart(this.state.currentOrder);
      }
    });
  }
```

Is there a way to move the `.then` function to resolve the Promise returned by `AsyncStorage.getItem()` inside of the OrderHistory model? I tried something like this but it didn't work:

orderhistory:

```
export default class OrderHistory extends Object {
  static async ordersPlaced() {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("myKey", "My value here");
    return AsyncStorage.getItem("myKey").then((value) => value);
  }
}
```

component:

```
  onBuyButtonPress() {
    let blah = OrderHistory.ordersPlaced();
    console.log(blah);
  }
```

But that prints `Promise {_45: 0, _81: 0, _65: null, _54: null}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is still asynchronous code, you'll have to deal with a Promise and use `.then` to get results. You can take a look at upcoming async/await JS feature, if you want to make code look synchronous, [here is a QA about it in react-native](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016685/how-to-use-await-key-word-on-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncStorage` methods return a `Promise` that you need to handle. To make it nicer and get rid of the `.then` callback hell, you can use the `async/await` syntax which still takes a `Promise` and "awaits" its completion:

```
static async ordersPlaced() {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem("myKey", "My value here");
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("myKey");
  //check your value, process it, etc.
  return value;
}
```