# how to display data in table using json in react js?

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

i have JSON like [this](http://31.216.37.143:8080/beautyappeal_dev/resources/util/category)

i want to use this JSON and display data in Table using react js.

this is how i display data from JSON file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import data from './data.json';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <ul>
        {
          data.map(function(movie){
            return <li>{movie.id} - {movie.title}</li>;
          })
        }
        </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

how to load JSON from URL and display it in table using reactjs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) the JSON once the component will mount, and when you eventually resolve it you can update the state of the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class App extends Component {
  // initially data is empty in state
  state = { data: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    // when component mounted, start a GET request
    // to specified URL
    fetch(URL_TO_FETCH)
      // when we get a response map the body to json
      .then(response => response.json())
      // and update the state data to said json
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }));
  }


  render() {
    return (
        <ul>
        {
          this.state.data.map(function(movie){
            return <li key={movie.id}>{movie.id} - {movie.title}</li>;
          })
        }
        </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

If you're unable to use `fetch`, you could use some other libraries like [superagent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) or [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). Or you could even fall back to good ol' `XMLHttpRequest`.

On another note, when building a list of component it is important they each child have a unique `key` attribute. I also updated that in the code, with the assumption that `movie.id` is

Example axios code:

```
axios.get(URL)
  .then(response => response.data)
  .then(data => this.setState({ data }));
```

**EDIT**: as trixn wrote in a reply, `componentDidMount` is the preferred place to fetch data. Updated code.

**EDIT 2**: Added axios code.

Comment: This is correct but `componentDidMount()`is the preferred lifecycle method to fetch data. `componentWillMount()` will be prefixed with `UNSAFE_` beginning with react 16.3 and will likely be removed in future react versions. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount.

Comment: I also wrote some nice alternatives. Libraries like superagent and axios makes it easier and more ergonomic to work with asynchronous HTTP requests, you could also use XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: should i install fetch first in my react app ? @Phillip

Comment: please tell me @Phillip

Comment: @Ahmad If you cannot use `fetch` your browser does not support it. You should use one of the alternatives I've listed. In my answer there is links to two libraries.

Comment: @Phillip can you please add code for axios library because i am already using it for http request (Form Submission) but i don't know how to load JSON using this library ...please add code because i am stuck into this problem since 2 days as i am new to react

Comment: @Ahmad I've added some example code, but I don't know if I'm doing you a disservice writing the code for you. You should learn to look through library documentation and API. I suggest you look at the axios documentation so you have an idea of what is going on :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use axios to send http requests.

It looks like this :

```
const response = await axios.get(your_url_here);
const items = response.data.items;
```

About await keyword : [How to use await key word on react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016685/how-to-use-await-key-word-on-react-native)

This is axios GitHub page for the docs : https://github.com/axios/axios

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you please write full code for me as i am new to react and i don't know where to write these 2 lines in your answer

Comment: I use Redux Store to store my objects, so copy/paste my code won't help you anyway. You can call a function, by example on a button onPress event, and add these lines inside this function. (Don't forget async before function keyword). Get your hands dirty, it's the better way to learn.

Comment: Please add sample code @WaLinke as i am new to react and i am unable to display data since 4 days...i will be great full if you help me...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **fixed Data table** to display the data from the json Response.Since the data is vast and it would be difficult to manage the conventional table, this would be a better alternative.

The documentation is given at

https://github.com/schrodinger/fixed-data-table-2/blob/master/examples/ObjectDataExample.js

This link will help you.