# How to extract output from async function - react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have got a question.
How do I get a result from function a async function?

This is my code:

```
function kakaoLogin() {
  return async dispatch => {
    RNKakaoLogins.login((err, result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
    console.log(result);
  };
}
```

this is result.
[image]

The first console.log(result) shows token!.
but second console.log(result) does not show anything.

I want to get same result from second console.log(result) as first console.log(result)

Answer (score 2):

```
function kakaoLogin() {
  return async dispatch => {
    RNKakaoLogins.login((err, result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
    console.log(result); // calling result outside its scope will not work
  };
}
```

What do you expect with a null result? You are using `result` outside of block.
If you want to do something in response. then you can make method call like.

```
function kakaoLogin() {
  return async dispatch => {
    RNKakaoLogins.login((err, result) => {
      console.log(result);
      doSomeWork(result);
      // you can call another method here when you get response.
    });
  };
}

function doSomeWork(result){
.. somework
}
```

Comment: Also you shouldn't be using an async result immediately after issuing an async call. You should be using a callback like @Khemraj suggests or a then() method for better readability.

Comment: I want to get token value from second console.log(result) like first console.log(result)

Comment: The first console.log(result); is executed after the async method resolves with the result. The second console.log(result); is executed with the result variable being undefined.

Comment: How will you use response when response did not come?

Comment: Your code executes like this RNKakaoLogins.login -> second console.log(result); -> RNKakaoLogins.login returns result -> first console.log(result);

Comment: You can use `async` `await` if you want to log just after login. For that you have to write appropriate code for login function. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34164475/6891563